# Using HttpContext cookies is there a way to allow it to be deleted on browser close as well as having an expiry time?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, cookies

The title sums it up. I have cookies created that I have put a 30 minute expiry timer on. Before adding this the cookie was deleted when the browser was closed, now the timer seems to keep it even after it is closed.

I want to be able to use both, so that the cookie will still be deleted when the browser is closed and also deleted if it is still open after 30 minutes. Is this possible?

My web app is done in .Net Core 3.1 following MVC using C#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's where you set the expiry of cookies. So that they become invalid as soon as the expiry duration elapsed.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

Comment: Hi Chetan, I've got it working with an expiry time, but then the cookie no longer deletes when the browser is closed, which I still want it to do as well.

Comment: I am not sure if browser delete cookies on itself when closed. https://forums.asp.net/t/1939582.aspx?how+to+delete+cookies+on+browser+close+

Comment: Maybe you can implement it yourself. Use an encrypted cookie with `session` expiry and keep an expiry date on cookie value and validate it on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an alternative that works how I want. Instead of using HttpContext cookies, I used HttpContext Session, which allows me to set an idle time out as well as deleting the data on browser close.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: 2 Why's:
- Why do you want to remove the cookie on browser close? The browser handles this using the expiry setting
- Why don't you put the expiry of the cookie on the 'idle time out' that you described above. 
In short: using session to store data is the old way of programming and to be avoided at all cost.

Comment: Hi @sander , This is being used in a system that has the user logged in to their windows authentication account by default but has the ability to let others log in instead, the alternative logged in username is what I want stored in a cookie/session and need it removed on a timer and when the browser closes in case the user forgets to log out.

Comment: Ok, on login check if a cookie exists, if it does overwrite or delete it. If it doesn't, create it.